# pysurvival installs, but throws an exception on import

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use `pysurvival` library from an python 3 console application.

I have installed the module per the instructions [here](https://square.github.io/pysurvival/installation.html).

When I try to import the model,

```
from pysurvival.models.survival_forest import ConditionalSurvivalForestModel
```

I get the following error

```
python3(2454,0x10841adc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff90ea5950: pointer being freed was not allocated
python3(2454,0x10841adc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

However, just importing the library passes through with no errors.

```
import pysurvival
```

My envrionment:
macOS Catalina - 10.15.3
I have both Python2 and Python3 on my machine.